# django views the cartItems which is called from Models is showing error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

hello I'm trying to get cartitems from models with related name and the cartitem is getting error in views what so i do ?

here is my view--

```
def cart(request):

    cart = None
    cartitems = []

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, completed=False)
        cartitems= cart.cartitems.all()


    context = {"cart": cart, "items": cartitems}
    return render(request, "cart.html", )


def add_to_cart(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    products_id = data["id"]
    products = Product.objects.get(id=products_id)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, completed=False)
        cartitem, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, products=products)
        cartitem.quantity += 1
        cartitem.save()
        print(cartitem)
    return JsonResponse('it works', safe=False)
```

Models.py---

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'hatkesh_cart'


class CartItem(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='items')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='cartitems')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.products.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'hatkesh_cartitems'
```

and the error is------

```
`Cannot access member "cartitems" for type "Cart"
  Member "cartitems" is unknown`
```

error is coming from views.py

I have tried different related names but it still not works !!
I was trying to call cart items to cart

Comment: Put Cart model in question